# How can we see the reason and more details for Staging error while pushing Ruby application?

Tags: ruby, ibm-cloud, staging

We are working to deploy a Ruby application on Bluemix, but we face the below Staging failure error with no details. We need to know how we can see the reason of the failure and more details about the error, so we can fix it.

```
$ cf logs reporter-123 --recent Connected, dumping recent logs for app reporter-123 in org ..@eg.ibm.com / space dev as ..@eg.ibm.com...

2015-06-25T17:56:30.27+0200 [API/0] OUT Updated app with guid 264dd489-78ea-4fb5-a055-86112ecc675f ({"name"=>"reporter-123", "command"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "instances"=>1, "memory"=>512, "disk_quota"=>1024, "environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})
2015-06-25T17:57:03.13+0200 [API/2] OUT Updated app with guid 264dd489-78ea-4fb5-a055-86112ecc675f ({"state"=>"STOPPED"}) 
2015-06-25T17:57:11.21+0200 [DEA/45] OUT Got staging request for app with id 264dd489-78ea-4fb5-a055-86112ecc675f 
2015-06-25T17:57:25.97+0200 [API/7] OUT Updated app with guid 264dd489-78ea-4fb5-a055-86112ecc675f ({"state"=>"STARTED"}) 
2015-06-25T17:57:26.27+0200 [STG/45] OUT -----> Downloaded app package (272K) 
2015-06-25T17:57:26.72+0200 [STG/45] OUT -----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (2.2M) 
2015-06-25T17:57:28.12+0200 [STG/0] OUT -------> Buildpack version 1.4.1 
2015-06-25T17:57:28.81+0200 [STG/0] OUT -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails 
2015-06-25T17:57:29.93+0200 [STG/0] OUT -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.2 
2015-06-25T17:57:30.13+0200 [STG/0] OUT -----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12 
2015-06-25T17:57:30.89+0200 [STG/0] OUT Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
2015-06-25T17:58:57.42+0200 [STG/0] OUT Using rake 10.4.2 
2015-06-25T17:58:57.91+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing CFPropertyList 2.3.0 
2015-06-25T17:58:58.06+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing i18n 0.7.0 
2015-06-25T17:58:58.56+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing minitest 5.5.1 
2015-06-25T17:58:58.95+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing thread_safe 0.3.4 
2015-06-25T17:58:59.09+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing builder 3.2.2 
2015-06-25T17:58:59.51+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing mini_portile 0.6.2 
2015-06-25T17:58:59.60+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing erubis 2.7.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:00.31+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing json 1.8.2 
2015-06-25T17:59:00.39+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing mime-types 2.4.3 
2015-06-25T17:59:00.59+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing nailgun 0.0.3 
2015-06-25T17:59:00.91+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing rack 1.6.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:01.06+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing arel 6.0.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:01.25+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing encryptor 1.3.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:01.52+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing ice_nine 0.11.1 
2015-06-25T17:59:02.47+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing coffee-script-source 1.8.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:02.92+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing execjs 2.2.2 
2015-06-25T17:59:03.32+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing hitimes 1.2.2 
2015-06-25T17:59:03.61+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing thor 0.19.1 
2015-06-25T17:59:03.67+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing connection_pool 2.1.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:03.95+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing equalizer 0.0.11 
2015-06-25T17:59:04.30+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing multipart-post 2.0.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:04.65+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing formatador 0.2.5 
2015-06-25T17:59:04.72+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing excon 0.44.4 
2015-06-25T17:59:05.17+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing multi_json 1.10.1 
2015-06-25T17:59:05.44+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing ipaddress 0.8.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:05.48+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing net-ssh 2.9.2 
2015-06-25T17:59:05.62+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing inflecto 0.0.2 
2015-06-25T17:59:06.11+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing hashie 3.3.2 
2015-06-25T17:59:06.45+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing hike 1.2.3 
2015-06-25T17:59:07.55+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing honeybadger 2.0.6 
2015-06-25T17:59:25.17+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing pg 0.18.1 
2015-06-25T17:59:25.17+0200 [STG/0] OUT Using bundler 1.7.12 
2015-06-25T17:59:25.77+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing tilt 1.4.1 
2015-06-25T17:59:26.29+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.2 
2015-06-25T17:59:26.84+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3 
2015-06-25T17:59:26.84+0200 [STG/0] OUT Using rdoc 4.2.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:27.64+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing redis 3.2.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:28.23+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing ruby-ole 1.2.11.8 
2015-06-25T17:59:28.74+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing ffi 1.9.8 
2015-06-25T17:59:29.29+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing temple 0.7.5 
2015-06-25T17:59:29.56+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing sass 3.4.9 
2015-06-25T17:59:29.85+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing tariffic 0.2.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:30.18+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing fission 0.5.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:30.58+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing descendants_tracker 0.0.4
2015-06-25T17:59:30.82+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing tzinfo 1.2.2 
2015-06-25T17:59:31.92+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing rmagick 2.15.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:32.27+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing mail 2.6.3 
2015-06-25T17:59:32.32+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing rack-test 0.6.3 
2015-06-25T17:59:32.59+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing coffee-script 2.3.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:32.83+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing attr_encrypted 1.3.4 
2015-06-25T17:59:33.27+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing timers 4.0.1 
2015-06-25T17:59:33.37+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing uglifier 2.7.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:33.73+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing fog-json 1.0.0 
2015-06-25T17:59:33.90+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing net-scp 1.2.1 
2015-06-25T17:59:33.94+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing faraday 0.9.1 
2015-06-25T17:59:34.29+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3 
2015-06-25T17:59:34.42+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing sprockets 2.12.3 
2015-06-25T17:59:34.86+0200 [STG/0] OUT Installing redis-namespace 1.5.1 
2015-06-25T17:59:35.60+0200 [STG/0] ERR 
2015-06-25T17:59:36.30+0200 [API/7] ERR encountered error: Staging error: failed to stage application: 
2015-06-25T17:59:36.30+0200 [API/7] ERR Script exited with status 255
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting CF tracing by issuing the following command:

```
set CF_TRACE=true
```

This will generate quite a bit of data, so when pushing your app you may want pipe it to a file i.e:

```
cf push <your_app> > pipedData.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [blog post](https://jeffsloyer.io/2015/03/05/tips-for-migrating-ruby-on-rails-applications-to-bluemix/) on some tips and tricks for getting your Ruby app working.

I would first try changing the Ruby buildpack you are using, you can do this by the following.

```
cf push myappname -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack.git
```